# Installing WIneHQ on Ubuntu 22.04, how to escape this dependency hell?

Tags: wine, dependencies, games

I am trying to install WineHQ on Ubuntu 22.04.1. I followed instructions from winehq.org, but when I try to run:

```bash
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.2~jammy-1)
```

Now, when I try to install wine-stable:

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libpulse0 (>= 0.99.1-1~) but it is not installable
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
 libcurl4 : Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
 libdbus-1-3 : Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
               Recommends: dbus
 libgphoto2-port12 : Depends: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8) but it is not installable
 libgstreamer1.0-0 : Depends: libunwind8 but it is not installable
 libsane1 : Depends: libsnmp40 (>= 5.9.1+dfsg) but it is not installable
            Depends: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.22) but it is not installable
            Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.1.1-5)
            Recommends: ipp-usb but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libpulse0 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libunwind8 but it is not installable
                     Depends: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.21) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libosmesa6 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
```

When i try to install libpulse=1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1, it wants to uninstall my desktop:

```bash
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-gnome-shell gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-initial-setup gnome-remote-desktop
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-tweaks
  libcanberra-pulse libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-utils ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session
```

I have tried to install it with aptitude but with no success. I really want to stay with Linux only but if I can't run Windows programs, I will be forced to dual boot it :/

Comment: So what is the correct version?

Comment: "*I really want to stay with Linux only but if I can't run Windows programs, I will be forced to dual boot it*" Avoid ridiculous hyperbole. WineHQ vs Dual Boot are not the only two alternatives. You could install Wine from the Ubuntu repositories. You could try a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Your "dependency hell" is caused by using the wrong version. Suggest to the nice folks at winehq.org to update their instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)